# Role of tautomerism and its difference from hyperconjugation

Tags: organic-chemistry, tautomer, hyperconjugation

I would like to know the role of tautomerism, if any, in increasing stability of an organic compound. Moreover, how is it different from that of hyperconjugation?

I know that hyperconjugation involves shifting of protons between adjacent
atoms in different hypothetical structures to form a practical hybrid structure.

I am not clear with tautomerism, so kindly deliver a precise explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Tautomerism basicially means that you have different isomers that are able to convert into each-other. This is not really similar to hyperconjugation which is an electronic effect in a given molecular geometry. The main difference between them is that hyperconjugation is thought to be a property of a given molecular geometry while tautomerization is an equlibrium between separate, distinct, stable configurations.

There are many types of tautomerizations, as explained for example on the [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautomer) Probably the most well-known type of tautomerisation is the keto-enol tautomerisation, which is an equilibrium between a ketone molecule and an enol (an alcohol connected to an $sp^2$ carbon). The equilibrium between two isomers is the explanation why enols are only stable under special scenarios: they tautomerise into ketons! Another important example for tautomerism is the equlibrium between the chain and the ring isomers for sugars.

So again: tautomerism is an equilibrium between different (real, existing) isomers as opposed to hyperconjugation which is just defined within a single structure.

Comment: Relevant definitions in the Gold Book: [tautomerism](https://doi.org/10.1351/goldbook.T06252), [hyperconjugation](https://doi.org/10.1351/goldbook.H02924)

Comment: It would probably be good to mention that tautomerism cannot enhance stability of a given molecular structure as it is dependent on its relative instability towards another isomer.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I was thinking about mentioning that, but then I realized that it probably affects the stability of the given tautomer by some second-order topological resonance effects. So I believe that pent-1-ene-1-ol is more stable than pent-2-ene-1-ol due to the possibility of the former one to tautomerise. Since this is just my gut feeling and would be hard to rationalize (at least in a StackOverflow post), I thought I would just not mention it.

Comment: Stability is (and cannot be) an absolute concept, you have to know the common state you are referring it to. That is why questions like tho one posed are generally hard to answer completely. However, we know in case of hyperconjugation, which is a special form of resonance, that a description with this effect is energetically lower. We cannot say that for tautomerism. Like you said this is an equilibrium and we have to asses stability for each structure itself. It may happen that other isomers are even lower (or higher) in energy, but that has nothing to do with tautomerism.

Comment: I pray to disagree: even for a simple symmetric two-state quantum system one can easily see that there is a coupling between the two separate energy levels, and the Rabi oscillation between them causes the system to be dynamically more robust. If we are not talking about a cryogenically stabilized single molecular entity (and even there we got tunnelig splitting!) then there is always an interaction between the two regions of phase space. And this results in a phase space volume that is bigger for a given energy, which, in my understanding, is a pretty absolute characterization of stability.

Comment: Let's agree to disagree then. I think this discussion is not helpful to the OP; if you really want to continue it, you can find me in [chat].

Comment: Just for OP: as in the comments by Martin. Retain that tautomers ARE compounds while mesomers ARE NOT. Teachers like to stress that but if their pupils have a clear idea of resonance (whatever the theory used) there shouldn't really be confusion. If the simbol used among mesomers would be ¤ instead of a double arrow ←→ one can't really mix up the two things.